# Numpy 1-dim array vs 2-dim array with one of the dimension having length 1

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array

In Matlab there is no concept of 1 dimensional array. All arrays have at least two dimensions. All "vectors" are either "row vectors" (1xn arrays) or "column vectors" (nx1 arrays).

In NumPy, on the other hand, arrays can also be one dimensional. So there is the concept of "pure vector" (dimension n),  "row vector" (dimension 1xn) and "column vectors" (dimension nx1).

This is giving me headaches now that I am moving from Matlab to Python.

As an example consider the case where I have to shift the rows of an n x k (n is generally big, but k can be 1) matrix, call it A, down by one row and then add a row of zeros a the first row.

In Matlab I would just do

```
[n, k] = size(A);
B      = [zeros(1,k); A(1:end-1,:)];
```

In Numpy, I would like this to work not only on a 2-dimensional input but also on a 1-dimentional one.
So a *working* solution would be

```
import numpy as np

if A.ndim == 1:
    B = np.concatenate((np.zeros(1), A[:-1]), axis=0)

if A.ndim == 2:
    (n, k) = A.shape
    B = np.concatenate((np.zeros((1,k)), A[:-1,:]), axis=0)
```

But this is way to heavy. Is there a better (more coincise) way?

More in general, I always have this problem: if I wrote a function that takes a 2 dimensional array (n x k), call it `arr`, *where k can very well be 1*, the function might fail on 1 dimensional arrays (for example if I do `arr[0,:]`).
But I would like it to work also on 1 dimensional arrays, since they are morally the same thing as 2 dimensional arrays in which one of the dimensions is 1.

Sure one way out would be to put something like

```
if arr.ndim == 1
    arr = arr.reshape((arr.shape[0],1))
```

at the very beginning of the function, so that then the function is guaranteed to have a 2 dimensional array to work with.

But this is not fully satisfactory. For example, it could be the case that my function returns an array of the same shape of the input (nxk). But if the input were one dimensional, I would like it to return something one dimensional as well, not a (nx1). So to take care of this case, I would need to add other lengthy if statements and reshaping, which would make my code look even heavier and uglier.

What's the best way out?

Comment: While those dimension tests may add to the length of the code, they don't make much difference in run time.  You could hide that code in a function.  `numpy` functions make adjustments like this all the time.  Look for example at `np.atleast_2d`, or how `vstack`, `hstack` and `column_stack` expand on the basic `concatenate`.  The `keep_dims` parameter of functions like `np.sum` can be handy, as well as understanding the difference between indexing with `0`, [0]` and `0:1`.  For some reason the transition from MATLAB to `numpy` wasn't that painful for me.

Comment: As I was reading (very weel written question, by the way) I was going to suggest your `reshape`-based approach, only with another `reshape` at the end to restore the original number of dimensions, which you would need to store initially in a variable

Comment: `like it to return something one dimensional as well, not a (nx1)` - [`.squeeze()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) that extra dimension out at the end of the function. The best way out might be to just start using Numpy and get used to the way it *works* unless you can find another suitable package to accomplish what you want. If you are asking for package/library recommendations that is off topic at SO.

Comment: @wwii "getting used to the way [Numpy] works" is exactly what I am trying to do!!! If you perceive otherwise I would love if you told me a more NumPythonic way of thinking!!!

Comment: @LuisMendo Thank you! I would really try and avoid this kind of logic if possible. It would just create mess.. of that I am sure...

Comment: @hpaulj Didnt know the keep_dims flag. With that I would be able to get 1d arrays out of my way completely. But I am not sure this is the way numpy is supposed to work (?). Let's see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I perceive the "strictness" of numpy (compared to MATLAB) when it comes to array sizes as an advantage, I feel like it makes many things more predictable.

I propose following solution to your first problem, which might contain some useful tools for tackling future problems. The first tool is the ["ellipsis" (`...`)](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/constants.html#Ellipsis) object, which can be used in indexing. When you see these three dots in indexing, you can think of it as replacing as many `:` as necessary. For example if `A.shape = (42,2021,69,7)` then `A[..., 1, :]` is the same as `A[:, :, 1, :]`. And here I should add that it is quite clear that you can only use one of these per indexing expression. It is a very useful thing to have in order to write functions  that deal with arrays  of an arbitrary amount of dimensions.

The second (which is not necessary for this answer) is that you can use that for things like `np.ones` or `np.zeros` etc you always have the corresponding function `np.ones_like` or `np.zeros_like` which let's you avoid many cumbersome computations.

So in the following we use these to first create a new array that has the right shape without having to do any arithmetic. We just call `np.zeros_like` on the thing we'd like to replace (in this case the last "hyper-row" of `A`, but it could be any of them). And at the same time the ellipsis operator conveniently deals with any number of dimensions we might have present:

```python
import numpy as np  
def f(A):
  u = np.zeros_like(A[-1:, ...]) # np.zeros(A[-1:, ...].shape)
  v = A[:-1,...]
  return np.concatenate([u,v], axis=0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY7PioMwEIfvPsXcmkAami29CB58DpEiNdJgnYT8kbYv7050C7tLDw0EJr/MfPO5R7xaPC6LmZz1ETBN7gFdAHRF0esBhrO99azmZQFgBqgl9maCqgKVEwCvY/JI7fJi8dJFjXQZo/dTexuY4gLqptyrlorubkJ14MV/1tfGQgEjVJSHa@f0R3imxMhfK0T5Z8mq/6OeiPsaOt/MqFnd7FUpQErZcmqY8@IVkhMKnDcY2W5VCTsBabMSMG9FHnpv1yQxt788NtKQpS1qcj4JTuddfsofy/IN)

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer. I have a few thoughts.a) Why do you see the "strictness" of numpy as an advantage. I would love to see what i am missing since I see it as a disadvantage!!

Comment: b) One thing I did not know is that you can index an n dim array with just one index. This i discovered while playing with your answer. So would it be fine to modify your answer with A[-1:] instead of A[-1:, ...] and A[:-1] instead of A[:-1, ...]. I suspect this would be completely equivalent. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: c) You gave me a fish but I still cannot fish (probably because I am dumb). For example what if i wanted to have a function take takes an nxk matrix and gives you an nx1 matrix with the sum of each row across columns. if I were sure that the input is 2-dim I could obviously do np.sum(A, axis=1). But this would again fail on 1-dim inputs on which i would like the output to be the same as the input. Any elegant solution here?

Comment: @Chicken (a) In matlab the first two dimensions of a multidimensional array basically get some special treatment with special rules. These can be useful if you deal only at most two dimensional arrays (which can be the case when you use "textbook"-linear algebra tools). But if you have an arbitrary number of dimensions it is cumbersome that the first two get a special treatment, and in numpy all dimensions are "created equal", so it is a lot more consistent in that regard.

Comment: (b) that is correct, this works nicely as long as you just access the leading dimensions. I like using the ellipsis operator anyway just to explicitly tell the reader that there are more dimensions present.

Comment: (c) Here it feels like you want to apply the matlab intuition (as I mentioned in (a)), which results in again having a special case for the 1d-case. Summing a long the second dimension (`dim=1`) only makes sense for arrays with two or more dimensions. It just simpliy is not defined for a 1d-array in numpy, and from the numpy perspective rightly so, due to the consistency: Even if you forget what dimension you sum over, you know that `.sum(dim=X)` always returns an array that has one dimension less than the input, but what you're suggesting is a special case for when you have one dimension.

Comment: So I don't see a "better" solution than just a plain "if/else" for this particular case, and I hope I could motivate why this is the case.  - I'm not suggesting that what you want to do is not valid, I'm merely trying to show how the two different languages approach things differently, along with my preference for the one of them:)

Comment: Thanks a lot again. I see your points. This leads me to my last question then: are there other data structures still in numpy which might be easier to work with from my point of view (ie all arrays are 2d)? Maybe np.matrix or something like that is worth having a look at?

Comment: As far as I know there is no such thing. (Also `np.matrix` is deprecated, now `np.array` does the same things.) The only resource I know that might help a little bit is this one: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html

Comment: Yeah this tutorial I did know. But did not know that np.matrix was deprecated. For all the rest that God may bless you Sir. Thanks again